# 10 Values to run on same SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I got 10 values in my array and I am currently looping my query for each array. Is there a way to put it in one statement without looping?

```
SELECT
    a.OrderSuffix AS 'OrderSuffix',
    COUNT(1) AS 'CountNew'
FROM
    dbo.Orders AS a,
    dbo.OrderStatus AS b
WHERE
    b.Status = 'Finished' AND
    a.OrderSuffix = array
```

Comment: You mean something like `a.OrderSuffix in ('A','B','C')`?

Comment: Yes, an IN clause or TVP for example, the best/easiest way depends on what you are calling the SQL from - which you need to add to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was able to get it.

Comment: Let's say I want to put in a date, too, per value of the array. I wanna count all new data based on a variable date. Should I put IN as well?

Comment: Without knowing the details it's basically a guess... but yes, you can put dates in `in` clause too, and they can also be variables, like `in (@date1, @date2, @date3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.OrderSuffix AS 'OrderSuffix',
    COUNT(1) AS 'CountNew'
FROM
    dbo.Orders AS a,
    dbo.OrderStatus AS b
WHERE
    b.Status = 'Finished' AND
    a.OrderSuffix IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ')
GROUP BY
    a.OrderSuffix
```